# BroadcastReceiver to start a service when device is turned on?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I can get the BroadcastReceiver to work but I'm not sure why the code for the intent to start the service has an error.

```
public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent backGround = new Intent(this,BackGround.class);
        startService(backGround);
    }
}
```

The error's are with the new intent(this,BackGround.class) and startService(); now I think I need to implement the service class for the startService method and (this) needs to be something else but I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: what are the errors? Please post your logcat

Comment: I think you should use `context` not `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it!

```
public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
             context.startService(new Intent(context, BackGround.class));
         }
}
```

and don't forget to include service in manifest as well.